# HttpUrlConnection Android Studio

Tags: android, connection, apk

someone can help me?
I've tryied for days to do a UrlConnection in Android Studio, but I've failed and I dont know why.

Here is my code:

```
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                url = new URL("http://www.google.com");

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();

                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                //THE APK STOPS HERE

                InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = isw.read();
                while (data != -1) {
                    char current = (char) data;
                    data = isw.read();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    //urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
```

I've already add the INTERNET and ACESS_NETWORK_STATE permissions.
Thanks

Comment: Its simply dont work

Comment: Guys, I've discovered the problem, I've tried to place the code, directly in onclick event. I was needed to put the code inside a Thread.

BUT, now, I receive the error "java.io.FileNotFoundException:"...
Someone? lol

Answer (score 0):

Replace   `InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();`
with 
`InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());` and try it may be help you

Comment: Hi man, thanks for you help, but i've tryied this change, but the code stops the same way.
Actually, he dont stop, simply dont pass from this line. I've tested with one TextView, putting the string "test", and before this line, the text has changed, but after this line, have no change.

I'm going crazy with this. I have no idea why this dont work

Answer (score 0):

```
        int data = isw.read();
        while (data != -1) {
            char current = (char) data;
            data = isw.read();
        }
```

you could check this code .you just read data,but there is no place you store it.

Comment: i've putted a TextView to place the code, and his not showed.
After, I've writed "test" in this TextView, and nothing.
In code, where its commited "THE APK STOPS HERE", its where the apk work stops

Answer (score 0):

I resolve de problem.
The crash problem was because the code isn't inside a Thread, and the "File not Found" problema, it's a server problem, that I have fixed a minutes ago.
Thanks all